# Find probability that a set contains 2 values from an outcome

Tags: probability

> For any outcome $\omega=(a_1,\dotsc,a_6)$, let $R(\omega)$ be the set $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_6\}$.
>
> This is the set of numbers that showed up at least once in the different rolls. For example, if $\omega=(2,2,5,2,3,5)$, then $R(\omega)=\{2,3,5\}$.
>
> Find the probability that $R(\omega)$ has exactly two elements.

I understand that I have to think it like binary, but I don't really see what are the steps to find how to compute it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, per roll, you can only show 2 specific values. But you have to subtract the case that you get exact one elements:

$$P(\text{Set is has two elements}) = P(\text{Roll one or another specific value per roll six times})-P(\text{roll exactly one element six times}).$$

So, we have
$$\binom{6}{2}\left[\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^6-2\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^6\right]$$
where there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the $2$ elements to make the set.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation @probablyme , just a question: I don't really understand why we multiply by 2 the probability of P(roll exactly one element six times) ?

Comment: And also why we don't do like P(Roll one specific value per roll six times) - P(Roll an another specific value per roll one time) ?

Comment: Do you mean 2? Because, once we have chosen which two we want to be "success", then either we roll element 1 six times, or roll element 2 six times. Hence there are **2** ways to roll one element six times.

Comment: Yes! I think that works too. They will have the same probability, hence multiply by 2.